# SubSonic Oracle Provider

Tags: oracle, subsonic3

I'm all around the net trying to figure which is the best currently available subsonic 3 provider for Oracle.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, my fork on GitHub is still the "best" (or most complete) for use with Oracle ODP.NET.

https://github.com/rally25rs/SubSonic-3.0

https://github.com/rally25rs/SubSonic-3.0-Templates
(specifically [OracleDataProvider.ttinclude](https://github.com/rally25rs/SubSonic-3.0-Templates/blob/master/TemplateProviders/OracleDataProvider.ttinclude))

The stuff in my fork was slated to go into the next major release of SubSonic, but the entire project sort of lost steam, and development has pretty much stopped at this point, so a pull request was never made to get the Oracle and IBM DB2 support put back into the "main" SubSonic project.

However, the stuff that is in my fork, I used for over a year in a production application, before we moved off Oracle, so it definitely works.

It has been a while since I pulled any changes from the main SubSonic repository, so there might be bug fixes or other template changes in the main repositories that aren't in my fork.

Comment: Yep! I also think yours is the best :D Thank you for hard work! You're the best!!!!

Comment: For PostgreSQL you don't have any?

Comment: I'm not sure if there is anything out there for PostgresSQL.  I had made my fork specifically to implement Oracle ODP.NET support, and later also added IBM DB2 support, because that is what I needed for a production app that I was working on at my day job.  Someone out there might have code for PostresSQL, but I do not.

Comment: I know this is old, but how exactly do you use this. When I try to run the templates, the seems to try to generate sql server stuff.